# Force Refresh current page in Ionic 4 in ionViewWillEnter function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to force refreshing the current page in Ionic 4 in ionViewWillEnter ?

Comment: In general, questions that are just one sentence in length are too short for here. There is always more context and information that can be offered. I will try to put this on hold for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh Ionic4 page:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Note this will reload every time you get to the page. Maybe you can just add the `window.location.reload()` into a function that does something, and after the request has failed, you can reload it.

Comment: I think i found a solution using ionViewDidEnter instead

Comment: How to get rid the white screen after reload the page?